# Connect other server database

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a console app and want to connect other windows server where I have already created user, database table. In conf.xml I have

```
<configuration>
  <crypto location="172.16.10.34" database="Crypto_Pan" username="PinbySms" password="ASDasd123"/>
</configuration>
```

then my code is :

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = conf.getCrypto();

SqlConnectionStringBuilder bu = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

bu.DataSource = d["location"];
bu.NetworkLibrary = "DBMSSOCN";
bu.InitialCatalog = d["database"];

bu.IntegratedSecurity = false;
bu.UserID = d["username"];
bu.Password = d["password"];
SqlConnection thisConnection = null;

try
{
    thisConnection = new SqlConnection(bu.ConnectionString);
    thisConnection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("success connected");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("exeption: " + e.ToString());

    thisConnection.Close();

}
```

I have an error when my app try to connect this database:

> [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] = {"A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: The address is not correct or SQL Server is not configured to allow remote connections - Is that IP reachable? Can you connect with anything else?

Comment: Does the connection string from the connection string builder have the expected contents? Can other tools connect to that database with the same details? (And what's wrong with putting the connection string in the config: there's a whole section for them?)

Comment: I sure hope those are not your real credentials...

Comment: First, try to connect sql server from your machine with above credentials...  credetial might be wrong

Comment: Could be that that username/password authentication is allowed on server. Try with windows authentication.

Comment: thank you guys. there was not default port in sql configuration PROTOCOL MSQSQLSERVER  TCP/IP , i changed it to 1433 and  now it's ok.

Comment: @3vge If the credentials (username and password) you mention in your question are the REAL ones I would STRONGLY advice you to change them immediately. Real usernames and passwords should NEVER be put somewhere readable in the internet not even on this site here....at least as long as you don't want others to suddenly read the data you have or put things into your database that you don't want to have in there (like malware),...

Comment: To be able to access a remote computer the two computers must be in the same group.  Then you can use windows authentication only if the same user account is on both PCs.  SQL Server has two types of credentials for a database.  SQL and Windows.  If you are using SQL then you must include a username and password when connecting.  If you are using windows credentials then a windows account can be used.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for remark. conf.xml is other directory where other user  access denied as our admin said me.. 
 can u give me some advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was not default port in sql configuration PROTOCOL MSQSQLSERVER TCP/IP , i changed it to 1433 and now it's ok.